# Help with Incorporating Code for Pagination

Tags: visualforce, angularjs, pagination

I have created a visualforce page that displays an object and allows searching/sorting of the list with AngularJS and now I am trying to add pagination.

Here is a perfect example of what I'm looking for - http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview

Could anyone please help with incorporating this code into my own (below)?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

```
    <apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<style>
body { font-size: 12px !important; }
</style>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<apex:remoteObjects >
<apex:remoteObjectModel name="con_AppCatalog__c" fields="Name,Branch__c,Id,Functional_Area__c,Description__c" jsShorthand="dbContacts"/>
</apex:remoteObjects>
<script>
                    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.sortType = 'Name'; // set the default sort type
                $scope.sortReverse = false;
                $scope.contacts=[];
                $scope.searchText='';
                $scope.fetchContacts = function() {
                    var dbCon = new SObjectModel.dbContacts();
                    console.log(dbCon);
                    dbCon.retrieve({where: {
                        or:{
                            Name: {
                                like: '%'+$scope.searchText+'%'
                            },
                            Branch__c: {
                                like: '%'+$scope.searchText+'%'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                                    limit: 500
                                   },
                                   function(err, records, event){
                                       $scope.$apply(function () {
                                           if(err) {
                                               alert(err.message);
                                           }
                                           else {
                                               $scope.contacts.splice(0,$scope.contacts.length);
                                               records.forEach(function(record) {
                                                   $scope.contacts.push({"Name" :record.get("Name"),"Id" :record.get("Id"),"Functional_Area__c":record.get("Functional_Area__c"),"Description__c":record.get("Description__c"),"Branch__c":record.get("Branch__c")}); // it was % in place of $ with scope earlier
                                               });
                                           }
                                       });
                                   });
                };
            });
            </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="fetchContacts()">

<div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<label for="searchText">Search:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="searchText" id="searchText" ng-change="fetchContacts()"/>
</div>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead><tr>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
First Name
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Name' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Name' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Branch__c'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
Branch
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Branch__c' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Branch__c' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Functional_Area__c'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
Functional Area
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Functional_Area__c' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Functional_Area__c' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Description__c'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
Description
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Description__c' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes"></span>
<span ng-show="sortType == 'Description__c' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></span>
</a>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="c in contacts | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
<td><a href="https://toolingorg-cbpoit--toolingsand.cs32.force.com/s/detail/{{ c.Id }}"> {{ c.Name }} </a></td>
<td>{{ c.Branch__c }}</td>
<td>{{ c.Functional_Area__c }}</td>
<td>{{ c.Description__c }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>


</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi @Brandon, in evey post you have created so far, you seem to just be dumping your code and expecting everyone on the forum to tell you what you should do. I personally have never worked with angular, however, if you were to narrow down what problem you are facing, alongside any debugging you have done, that would greatly increase any chances of assistance from the community. Please take some time to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Cheers

Comment: Also, if you made it easier by providing a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/), it would help out a lot. As it is, you're asking us to either create custom objects and fields or heavily modify the code, which means that instead of a simple debug session, we have to spend a lot of time setting up just so we can even *begin* to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to coding, I've been trying to piece different things together to get this all to work in a short time frame. I thought maybe I could just throw the code from the example into mine somehow with a bit of tweaking and get it to work, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Imo, this is not a good way to start learning to code =(

Comment: I understand the basics. I've tweaked everything in my code to get it to work with my own objects. I just need to know where I need to plug in the example code and I can take it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for simple angularJs pagination filter

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="q" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter text">
    <select ng-model="pageSize" id="pageSize" class="form-control">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
     </select>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:q | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul

    >
        <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
            Previous
        </button>
        {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
        <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= getData().length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        $scope.pageSize = 10;
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.q = '';

        $scope.getData = function () {
          // needed for the pagination calc
          // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
          return $filter('filter')($scope.data, $scope.q)
     /* 
       // manual filter
       // if u used this, remove the filter from html, remove above line and replace data with getData()

        var arr = [];
        if($scope.q == '') {
            arr = $scope.data;
        } else {
            for(var ea in $scope.data) {
                if($scope.data[ea].indexOf($scope.q) > -1) {
                    arr.push( $scope.data[ea] );
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
       */
    }

    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }

    for (var i=0; i<65; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }


 }]);
```

// custom filter

```
angular.module.filter("startFrom", function() {
        //We already have a limitTo filter built-in to angular,
        //let's make a startFrom filter

        return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
 });
```